# Can not add values to a multidimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am new to C#. I am trying to make a matrix calculator but first I need the user to give me the size of and the contents of said matrix. I have 2 classes.

First class is as follows:

```
class Assignment1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the number of rows in the matrix: ");
        int row = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter the number of columns in the matrix: ");
        int columns = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        MatrixN matrix =new MatrixN(row, columns);

        int i = 0;
        for (double x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for(double y = 0; y < columns; y++)
            {

                if(i == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter first value of the matrix: ");
                    matrix[x, y] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    i++;
                }
                else if (i == row * columns)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter last value of the matrix: ");
                    matrix[x, y] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    i++;
                }
                Console.Write("Enter nest value of the matrix: ");
                matrix[x, y] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second class is:

```
 class MatrixN
{

    double[,] m;

    public MatrixN(int row, int column)
    {
        m = new double[row, column];
    }
```

I keep getting the error: *cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of MatrixN* for the code

```
matrix[x, y] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix` is a variable of type `MatrixN`. The type `MatrixN` does not support the subscription/indexing operation, so you cannot access the value `matrix[i, j]`, nor set the value `matrix[i, j] = v;`.

You can either expose the `m` member variable of the `MatrixN` class (by making it public), and set/access the value of `matrix.m`, or write your own index operator:

```
class MatrixN {
   private double[,] inner;
   public double this[int x, int y] {
       get { return inner[x, y]; }
       set { inner[x, y] = value; }
   }
}
```